# How to reset multiple captcha on same page with contact form 7?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I have two contact from 7 on single page, i want to refresh captcha once user submit form, but its working for one form and if user form submit 2nd form its also refresh captcha of 1st form

Comment: I am looking for help, how to reset captcha by id i know how to reset single captcha by additional setting

Answer (score 2):

For both forms:

**Go to admin=> Contact => Edit Contact form => Additional Settings**

Just go to that location and paste the below mentioned code

> on_sent_ok: "grecaptcha.reset();"

DONE with the code, now check your recaptcha will behave as per your requirement.

This may help for you.

Comment: As i mentioned in my comments i have already set on_sent_ok: "grecaptcha.reset();" in addition setting for both form.

But its working for only one, when I will submit 2nd form its resetting captcha of first form.

Comment: Both forms has same id or different ID?